# ftp_get corrupts audio files

Tags: php, linux, ftp, apache2

This could be server related, but for some reason on the server B when I fetch files from FTP location via ftp_get are downloaded by when you open the file only first second is played, rest is unplayable.

On Server A everything works fine.

What can this issue be and how may it be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audio files must be transferred in binary/image mode or they could become corrupt (due to line ending translation). Make sure both the initial upload as well as any subsequent download is performed in the correct mode.